# How to copy first row of a table using Jquery?

Tags: jquery, html-table, row, clone

I need to clone first row of table. I added a new button, but nothing happens!
`#add_button` is placed after the table.

> (First row is the header)

```
$('#add_button').click(function(event) {
var new_line = $(this).prev('table').find('tr:eq(1)');
$(this).prev('table').append(new_line);
});
```

Comment: please share your html code too so that we can help you better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to clone the table row and then append so that original row will not move, see below code

**NOTE** - use variable to table element so that you don't have to call `prev('table')` again to find table and then append. Also this code will work provided that you have `table` before `add_button`, there must not be any other element in between.

```
$('#add_button').click(function(event) {
   var $table = $(this).prev('table');
   var new_line = $table.find('tr:eq(1)').clone();
   $table.append(new_line);
});
```

Comment: Thanks. How can I select previews table if there is some tags between them?

Comment: you can have id to table like `id="tableId"` (please make sure it must be unique through out the DOM) and use `$('tableId')` to get table, in this way if you change position of table then you don't need to modify your code. Same way you can make use of class attribute also if you don't want to use id. With class you can use `prevUntil('.classNameOfTable')`.

Answer (score 4):

You need to clone else you will be simply moving the existing row

```
$('#add_button').click(function (event) {
    var $table = $(this).prev('table'),
        $nrow = $table.find('tr:eq(1)').clone();
    $table.append($nrow);
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/0wtsfeht/)